# HTML form not submitting to a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is when every person fills out the form on my website all the data will be sent to the google sheet that I create for that specific contact form. I'm following a blog post https://dev.to/omerlahav/submit-a-form-to-a-google-spreadsheet-1bia

Everytime I follow the code below I get a error message saying that

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`

The

`const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet'];`

is calling the form element to trigger the data within the form elements. This goes inside of the HTML for like so

`<form name="submit-to-google-sheet"></form>`

```
const scriptURL = 'Google Script Link Here';
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet'];

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
});
```

**BETA LINK:** https://i8cp0-zzwqjbaw.instant.forestry.io/

**GITHUB:** assets/js/form.js I have the the code inside of this code: https://github.com/brandonpowell/pw/tree/master

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: I have upload the post with a beta link of example that going to help @Ruben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are trying to attach the event listener before the form loads into the HTML.

**Option 1**
Try adding your `form.js` at the end of the body

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- Include css and other meta data -->
 </head>
  <body>
    <!-- All other html -->

    <!-- Script tag goes at the end (when everything is loaded)-->
    <script src="form.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

***You HTML doesn't contains `body` tag, it is not a valid html.**

If that doesn't work try this.
**Option 2**

Wrap your `form.js` code in

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
 //All your code goes here...
});
```

Some useful resources
[Window load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)
[Defer and Async attribute](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/html-defer-async#:%7E:text=Async%20vs%20Defer,order%20as%20they%20are%20called)
[Javascript Topics](https://javascript.info/)

Comment: It's worked. So, I new person learning JS What are some best practices I should look for? When I'm learning JS?

Comment: Added some useful resource, you don't need to go through everything, If you stuck simply research or stackoverflow is your friend

Comment: Thank I'm going to now feel more confident in the site more